# ASP.NET IIS APPPOOL Identity Configuration Implications

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

Suppose we create a new application pool with name as AppPool1.

When AppPool1 uses identity as ApplicationPoolidentity, then, ASP.NET code runs using IIS APPPOOL\AppPool1.

I would like to know that, what happens if we set the identity of AppPool1 as:-

1. Local System
2. Network Service
3. Local Service

I would like to know the username under which ASP.NET code runs.

Comment: What happens?  Then the app pool runs as those users.  I don't see how it could be any simpler.

Comment: I would like to know the username under which ASP.NET code runs.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion.  You just listed the user names.

Comment: Just wondering whether there was DOMAIN\USERNAME type of thing/

Comment: Those are all local machine accounts.  They don't exist in a domain.  Typically it's NT AUTHORITY\Local System, etc.. NT AUTHORITY\ is a only for local built-in system accounts.  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service is a bit different in that when a process is running as that user and it connects to a network resource on a domain, it uses the computers domain account (machine name) to connect.